# Select missing months between 2 dates (in same year)

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get all months in which no transaction is placed for the same year (If different years is not possible)

This is my query to get transactions between 2 dates, but don't know how can I select only months for which transaction in database is missing

```
SELECT * 
FROM Installment 
WHERE OrderId = 1 
      AND InstallmentDate 
            BETWEEN cast('8/02/2014' as date) 
                AND cast('12/25/2014' as date)

InstallmentId   OrderId CustomerKey InstallmentAmount   InstallmentDate
    18             1      INS-1          3000           2014-09-03
    92             1      INS-1          3000           2014-10-13
   137             1      INS-1          3000           2014-11-05
```

in this case record for the 12th month and 8th month is missing, how can I get this with SQL Server Query ?

**Update**

```
select yymm.yy, yymm.mm
from (select distinct year(InstallmentDate) as yy, month(InstallmentDate) as mm
  from Installment
  where InstallmentDate BETWEEN '2014-09-02' and '2015-01-15'
 ) yymm left join
 Installment i
 on i.OrderId = 1 and
    year(i.InstallmentDate) = yymm.yy and
    month(i.InstallmentDate) = yymm.mm
where i.OrderId is not null;
```

Gordon's query is returning all the years and months from table between 2 dates, just by changing `i.OrderId is null` to `i.OrderId is not null` here is the out of his query

```
 yy      mm
2014     9
2014     10
2014     11
```

Expected Output (if possible)

```
 yy      mm
2014     12
2015     1
```

Comment: Without knowing the schema of the table you are working with, but assuming you have a `Transaction` column within the `Installment` table, have you tried adding an extra clause in your `WHERE` when, `Transaction IS NULL`?

Comment: with transaction I mean database record/row

Comment: Would you please share with us the expected output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the following recursive `CTE`:

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '2014-09-02'
DECLARE @end DATE = '2015-01-15'
;WITH IntervalDates (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, date)
    FROM IntervalDates
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, date)<=@end
)
SELECT YEAR(date) AS Year, MONTH(date) AS Month
FROM IntervalDates
```

you can get a list of all Years/Months between the two dates of interest:

```
Year    Month
==============
2014    9
2014    10
2014    11
2014    12
2015    1
```

Using `EXCEPT` on the above `CTE`:

```
;WITH IntervalDates (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, date)
    FROM IntervalDates
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, date)<=@end
)
SELECT YEAR(date) AS Year, MONTH(date) AS Month
FROM IntervalDates

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(InstallmentDate) AS yy, MONTH(InstallmentDate) AS mm
FROM Installment
WHERE  OrderId = 1 AND InstallmentDate BETWEEN @start AND @end
```

yields the required result set:

```
Year    Month
=============
2014    12
2015    1
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in SQL, you need to start with a list of months.  Assuming you have at least one record for each month in the table, you can then get the missing dates easily using a subquery.  The rest of the query is just a `left join` and checking for non-matches:

```
select yymm.yy, yymm.mm
from (select distinct year(InstallmentDate) as yy, month(InstallmentDate) as mm
      from Installment
      where InstallmentDate BETWEEN '2014-09-02' and '2015-01-15'
     ) yymm left join
     Installment i
     on i.OrderId = 1 and
        year(i.InstallmentDate) = yymm.yy and
        month(i.InstallmentDate) = yymm.mm
where i.OrderId is null;
```

Comment: please check the edited question, I want the missing month number/name/date so the record for that month should not be existed in database

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script. I retrieve all dates between the specified dates and use a `LEFT JOIN` to get those which are not present in your table:

```
DECLARE @startDate AS DATETIME, @endDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @dates AS TABLE (CurrentDate DATETIME)
SET @startDate = '2014-01-01'
SET @endDate = '2014-01-31';
with GetDates AS
(  
SELECT @startDate AS TheDate
UNION ALL  
SELECT DATEADD("DD", 1, TheDate) FROM GetDates
WHERE TheDate < @endDate  
) INSERT INTO @dates SELECT TheDate FROM GetDates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(d.CurrentDate), MONTH(d.CurrentDate) FROM @dates d
LEFT JOIN InstallmentDate i ON i.InstallmentDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND OrderId = 1
WHERE i.InstallmentDate IS NULL
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of is to have a date dimension table that contains (at least) date, and 1st of month then.  For creating one take a look at something like https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74957/best-approach-for-populating-date-dimension-table , although that one doesn't have firstOfMonthDate in it as my example show but the idea is the same.

then your query becomes

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    firstOfMonthDate
FROM
    dateRef dr
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    InstallmentDate i ON dr.date = i.InstallmentDate AND i.OrderId = 1
WHERE
    i.InstallmentDate IS NULL
AND
    dr.date BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate
```

change firstOfMonthDate for fiscal month etc. as required.  This would work across any range of dates you have in your table so different years wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: what is dateRef in the query ? and please explain the part "change firstOfMonthDate for fiscal month etc."

Thanks

Comment: That would be the date dimension table.   You create a table that has a large range of dates in, and other columns relating to features of that date, such as financial month etc.  The link to the stack exchange question shows an example of such a table.  You have that sat in your database and it can prove useful for solving problems like this.

Comment: The "change" bit is if you want another representation of what is missing in your transactions.  For instance if the date dimension included the column dayOfWeek, then you could easily change that query to show you the distinct days of the week you didn't have transactions on by changing the select to use that instead.